# Issues with docker build command and github

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a dev env as docker machine,

I created the following docker file

```
FROM rails:4.2
MAINTAINER Chen Kinnrot <kinnrot@gmail.com>
RUN mkdir -p /var/app
COPY Gemfile /var/app/Gemfile
WORKDIR /var/app
RUN bundle install
CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

When Running  `docker build -t dev .`

I get the follwing message

> fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>   github.com: Name or service not known

Why is that, and how can I solve this annoying issue?

Comment: Are you internally trying to fetch anything from Github ?

Comment: yes.. many gems are from github...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with VirtualBox / boot2docker; when switching networks, boot2docker sometimes looses its DNS information. See these issues; https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/776, https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1857

You can either try to restart the machine;

```
docker-machine stop default
docker-machine start default
```

Or set the right name server to the virtual machine;

```
docker-machine ssh default
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```